# CSS conditionally apply style based on availability of a property

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, conditional-statements

Does CSS have something like `@media` queries that would allow me to conditionally apply styles based on whether the browser implements a separate style?

You can conditionally apply a style that would override another like

```
background-color: #fff;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

which will only apply the second style if it is implemented in the browser, otherwise use the first-defined fallback.

I'd like to do something similar with a fallback based on whether the `-webkit-background-filter` property is available. I'd like to only apply transparency to an element if I can also give it a `-webkit-backdrop-filter`, otherwise make it opaque. Is this possible in pure CSS, or even with JavaScript?

Comment: Write CSS as normal, then see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552082/css-rules-for-webkit-based-browsers

Comment: @RichardHowell Close, but as of right now, Safari supports `-webkit-background-filter` and Chrome does not. This is better than nothing, though, as it will cover IE and Firefox.

Comment: With javascript, that is almost a no-brainer: Take a look at [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

Comment: You can also use `@supports` query, that should free you from the need to use JS

Comment: @Terry if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. I like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for most CSS properties via

```
document.body.style.hasOwnProperty(`prop name`)
```

The text of the property name changes like standard style properties, i.e.

`css` -webkit-background-filter <=> webkitBackgroundFilter `js`

As to applying the styles, depends on whether you add/change the styles of elements or add/change the CSS rules...